# "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with “Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools” error with MVS build tools installed

Tags: python, installation, pip, anaconda, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am trying to install OpenPIV on my anaconda distribution. I tried first pip installing and conda installing as it is advised [there](http://www.openpiv.net/openpiv-python/), and I also tried to compile it from source. Conda can't find the openpiv package in its repositories. Both when I tried to compile it from source or to pip install it, I got a "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with “Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools”. I already have installed Microsoft Build Tools for visual studio 2017 (and tried to reboot afterwards). Does anybody have a clue how to deal with that ?

The exact error is as following (for the pip installation) :

```
 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\tangu\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\tangu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-53nc_kez\\openpiv\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\tangu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-eu69lm7f-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\tangu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-53nc_kez\openpiv\
```

Comment: Did you install Build Tools or Redistributable?

Comment: I'm not really sure to know the difference between those two, I got them at this link, so I think I did install Build Tools : https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15

Comment: The difference is that Build Tools contain compiler and Redistributable does not. You need compiler. You need to configure it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671800/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/40886619/7976758.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! So now I am sure to have installed the compiler. It doesn't work though, but the error is not the same. I have followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724445/python-pip-on-windows-command-cl-exe-failed and also tried to update setup as advised there https://github.com/benfred/implicit/issues/76. Yet , when I try to build the library from source, i get "command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory", and for the pip install, "failed with exit status 2", "c1: fatal error C1355: entry point 'PDBSetServerFastFailMode' in mspdbcore.dll cant be found"

Comment: I've just updated the path, and now when I try to build from source, python finds cl.exe butI get "fatal error C1083"

Comment: "Cannot open include file"? Which one?

Comment: The error comes from \Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(10), the file it cannot open is 'vcruntime.h'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44133043/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fatal+error+C1083+Cannot+open+include+file+vcruntime.h

Comment: The solution in this did not work. I have finally solved the problem : I needed to install native development tools for python with visual studio installer. Thank you very much for your help and time :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)