# node-sass throws errors when installing on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, node-sass

I'm working on a front-end project with a friend who is on a Mac and has been able to install and run node-sass on his side. I'm running Windows 10, so when I've pulled the project and tried to run `npm install` I now get a bunch of errors coming from CI.exe like the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
file: 'vcruntime.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\..\src\libsass\src\check_nesting.cpp) [C:\Deve
lopment\xxx\xxx\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]
```

I've downloaded the C++ binaries, installed the node windows-build-tools, I've ensured that CI.exe is in PATH. I'm at my wits end!

I'm running node v8.2.1, npm v5.3.0, VS 2017 (v15.2, 26430.16 release)(C++ build tools installed, etc)

[Full npm debug log for running command `npm install node-sass` from project directory](https://paste.ee/p/nh8Nt)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290169/cannot-find-corecrt-h-universalcrt-includepath-is-wrong)? This is most definitely an issue with your Visual Studio installation.

Comment: same output unfortunately

Comment: If you are using VS 17 Community then your vcruntime file is at:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include  Maybe you can just edit your setup...anyway the compiler can't find it.  You need add the Community directory to the list of directories the compiler will search for header files. Right click on the project, select Properties, expand Configuration Properties, select VC++ Directories, and edit the Include Directories entry.  Maybe...

Comment: Hey @Drt, I should have specified, this is a front-end project, not C++ - I'm not using VS for compilation directly, but I know that the C++ build tools are required for working with node-sass on Windows

Comment: Any news on this ? I'm facing this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

**NodeJS v10 fix this** but new versions also have the same issue.

Also try :

```
npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-sass --save
```