# dlib build error in Visual Studio 2017 CE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, machine-learning, dlib

I had downloaded dlib-19.6 and I have OpenCV 3.3.0 running on my windows 10 laptop. Anytime I follow the instruction on dlib website to compile an example using Make 3.9, I get the following errors even after adding a working property page for OpenCV and PCL:

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory
2>bigint_kernel_1.cpp
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\crtdefs.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory
```

I will be glad if anyone can help out. Thank you so much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290169/cannot-find-corecrt-h-universalcrt-includepath-is-wrong

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will have a look at the link