# How to fix nvcc compiler error "missing cl.exe"

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, cl

I'm trying to compile a CUDA program with nvcc but I get an error

```
nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH
```

I can't find any cl.exe file in the NVIDIA GPU Toolkit folder so there's no way I can add any folder containing it to the PATH - where can I obtain the cl.exe file required?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error compiling CUDA from Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125826/error-compiling-cuda-from-command-prompt)

Comment: I don't think it does - I can't find any cl.exe to begin with so  there's no way I can add a folder containing it to the PATH. Also I'm not looking for any Visual Studio specific solution.

Comment: As per the Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options?view=msvc-170  cl.exe is a tool that controls the Microsoft C++ (MSVC) C and C++ compilers and linker. cl.exe can be run only on operating systems that support Microsoft Visual Studio for Windows. So there is a dependency here.

Comment: Please check the system requirements for CUDA, seems like you are missing a supported version of Microsoft Visual Studio.
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/

Comment: Okay thanks, I didn't realise there was a dependency with Visual Studio. I was just using it on the command line like g++ thinking it would work rip.

Answer (score 3):

CUDA development (on any platform) requires both the `nvcc` compiler as well as a suitable host code compiler.  On (native, not WSL2) Windows, the only host compiler supported for CUDA development is `cl.exe` - the host code compiler that ships with Visual Studio.

So to provide a proper environment for CUDA development on (native, not WSL2) Windows, you must install Visual Studio.

Other than that, follow the [instructions provided by NVIDIA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html) to get things set up.

An important aspect of those instructions is to install (a supported version of) Visual Studio **first**, then run the CUDA installer.  In this way, the CUDA installer locates all supported versions of Visual Studio, and performs additional integration steps necessary to have a sane compilation environment for Windows.

After you have done that, if you intend to compile from the command line, you may still need to [set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125826/error-compiling-cuda-from-command-prompt) your `PATH` [environment variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html) correctly, and also be sure to use the `-ccbin` switch for `nvcc` to specify the location of `cl.exe`.  Both location methods are necessary, in the general case, when compiling from the command line.