# CUDA Developer Toolkit: Display Driver failed installation

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I have the Nvidia Quadro NVS4200M along with Intel Integrated Graphics (on my laptop). I can't seem to get the **[CUDA 5.0 toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit)** installation to succeed.

I am running Windows 7 Enterprise Edition 64-bit. I tried the 64-bit desktop & notebook installers and the 32-bit installers.

All of them seem to fail with the error message **"Display Driver failed installation"**. I installed the latest drivers from [**here**](http://www.nvidia.com/object/quadro-notebook-win8-win7-winvista-64bit-307.45-whql-driver.html), and it is supposed to support CUDA-5.0, and despite that, the installation fails.

---

After failure, the libraries and binaries are present, but **NSight Eclipse** (which seems to have no standalone installation link) isn't installed. What could be the possible issue?

Comment: nsight eclipse is a linux-only tool.  You are running Windows.  It's not available on windows.  The similar tool on windows is nsight visual studio, which has a separate installer.  You should only be using the 64-bit installer.  If the display driver is new enough, it doesn't need to be installed or updated, so that message may not be a big deal, depending on your current display driver version.  When you attempted to install the 307.45 driver, what exactly was the result?

Comment: @RobertCrovella The 307.45 driver installed correctly. Can I just ignore the error message thrown by the Cuda toolkit installer?

Comment: Then you are probably fine.  Leave the driver alone, and install just the cuda toolkit and sdk portions of the cuda installer.  You don't need to update your driver.  If you are re-installing the cuda installer, just select no when it asks if you want to install the display driver, but yes for the cuda toolkit and sdk.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I thought Nsight Eclipse was cross-platform. I'd rather not install visual studio. It must be possible to compile and run from the command line? Could you point me to a link detailing that?

Comment: The only C/C++ compiler that is supported for windows cuda compilation by nvcc is cl.exe, which is the microsoft C/C++ compiler that comes with visual studio.  You can use the free version of visual studio, called visual studio express.   The easiest way to get started is to use visual studio 2010 (or 2008.  2012 can be made to work but requires extra effort).  You should install the cuda toolkit (cuda installer) *after* installing visual studio, so that it can find and automatically update your VS environment (build rules, etc.) for cuda compilation within VS.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks a lot! I'll do just that. P.S. You could put that comment down as an answer :)

Comment: I also had the same issue. The CUDA 5.0 installation program returned "Error: Display Driver failed installation". The original driver is the same as for Cthulhu: 307.45. Some of the SDK examples and of my own codes not requiring graphics run correctly (e.g., deviceQuery), but others requiring graphics (e.g., oceanFFT) do not (oceanFFT returns: "Support for necessary OpenGL extensions missing"). So perhaps it would be worth to investigate this issue better. How is the situation with you, Cthulhu? Does oceanFFT work correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. I'm not sure why the driver install failed in your case, but if you
   have a "recent" driver installed, it's not necessary to use the
   driver that comes with the cuda installer.  The cuda installer
   offers individual options to install the toolkit (required), samples
   (optional), and driver (required only if you have an older driver),
   so you can just select "no" when prompted for the driver install, to
   avoid this, assuming you have a recent driver or [installed one](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) such
   as [the 307.45 driver](http://www.nvidia.com/object/quadro-notebook-win8-win7-winvista-64bit-307.45-whql-driver.html).
2. You should always use a 64 bit installer if you have a 64 bit OS.
3. The only [officially supported C/C++ compiler for windows](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#windows) is cl.exe, the microsoft compiler that ships with either Microsoft Visual Studio ([the Express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-2010-express) will do, it is free), or [the Windows SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985860/compile-cuda-without-visual-studio-cannot-find-compiler-cl-exe-in-path)  (for command line use only).  You're free to experiment with other stuff, but your mileage may vary.  MS VS 2010 (and 2008) are the easiest to use.  MS VS 2012 can be made to work but [may require extra steps](http://blog.norture.com/2012/10/gpu-parallel-programming-in-vs2012-with-nvidia-cuda/).
4. I recommend installing cuda *after* installing Microsoft Visual Studio.  This is because the cuda installer should automatically find your VS installation and update some important files to make building cuda projects easier.
5. nsight Eclipse Edition is a linux-only tool (or mac).  It is not for windows use, and will not be installed by the windows cuda installers.  nsight EE provides an environment for code building, debugging, and profiling.  In windows, the corresponding operations can be done via MS VS IDE for code building, the standalone visual profiler for profiling, and using a separate plug-in, nsight visual studio edition, for debugging and profiling within visual studio.  Due to the way visual studio is constructed, nsight visual studio edition will not work with the free versions of visual studio.  nsight visual studio has [it's own separate installer](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition).
6. The windows [getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html) may also be of interest.