# install python module for using gpu on windows 8.1 x64

Tags: python, boost, cuda, gpu, pycuda

I have some trouble with installing python modules.
I wanna use gpu in a python script but I get some error while install modules
1- I install my graphic driver :  Geforce GT 650M
2- install cuda_5.5.31_winvista_win7_win8_win8.1_notebook_x64.exe
Now I want to install modules and these are errors :

Pyrit Error :

```
C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\pyrit-0.4.0>python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'cpyrit._cpyrit_cpu' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\pyrit-0.4.0>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'cpyrit._cpyrit_cpu' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\pyrit-0.4.0>
```

cpyrit-cuda Error:

```
C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\cpyrit-cuda-0.4.0>python setup.py build
The CUDA compiler and headers required to build kernel were not found. Trying to
 continue anyway...
running build
running build_ext
'nvcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
None
Failed to execute command 'nvcc -V'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 175, in <module>
    setup(**setup_args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 82, in run
    raise SystemError("Nvidia's CUDA-compiler 'nvcc' can't be " \
SystemError: Nvidia's CUDA-compiler 'nvcc' can't be found.

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\cpyrit-cuda-0.4.0>python setup.py install
The CUDA compiler and headers required to build kernel were not found. Trying to
 continue anyway...
running install
running build
running build_ext
'nvcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
None
Failed to execute command 'nvcc -V'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 175, in <module>
    setup(**setup_args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 82, in run
    raise SystemError("Nvidia's CUDA-compiler 'nvcc' can't be " \
SystemError: Nvidia's CUDA-compiler 'nvcc' can't be found.

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\cpyrit-cuda-0.4.0>
```

pycuda Error:

```
C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\pycuda-2013.1.1>python setup.py build
*** WARNING: nvcc not in path.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 218, in <module>
    main()
  File "setup.py", line 88, in main
    conf["CUDA_INC_DIR"] = [join(conf["CUDA_ROOT"], "include")]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 96, in join
    assert len(path) > 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\pycuda-2013.1.1>python setup.py install
*** WARNING: nvcc not in path.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 218, in <module>
    main()
  File "setup.py", line 88, in main
    conf["CUDA_INC_DIR"] = [join(conf["CUDA_ROOT"], "include")]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 96, in join
    assert len(path) > 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\pycuda-2013.1.1>
```

numpy error:

```
C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0>python setup.py build
Running from numpy source directory.
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
F2PY Version 2
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python
27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\l
ibs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', '
C:\\Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\
Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1522: User
Warning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs'
]
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1531: User
Warning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1534: User
Warning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python
27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1428: User
Warning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\lib
s']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1439: User
Warning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1442: User
Warning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler opti
ons
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler opt
ions
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
creating build
creating build\src.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\src.win-amd64-2.7\numpy
creating build\src.win-amd64-2.7\numpy\distutils
building library "npymath" sources
No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0>python setup.py install
Running from numpy source directory.
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
F2PY Version 2
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python
27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\l
ibs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', '
C:\\Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\
Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1522: User
Warning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs'
]
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1531: User
Warning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1534: User
Warning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python
27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1428: User
Warning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\lib
s']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1439: User
Warning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1442: User
Warning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler opti
ons
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler opt
ions
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
building library "npymath" sources
No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\numpy-1.8.0>
```

Boost Error :

```
C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\boost_1_55_0>bootstrap.bat
Building Boost.Build engine
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
Please consult bootstrap.log for furter diagnostics.

You can try to obtain a prebuilt binary from

   http://sf.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=72941

Also, you can file an issue at http://svn.boost.org
Please attach bootstrap.log in that case.

C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\boost_1_55_0>
```

Someone here tell me how I install nvcc ,and where I can download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing several things here.

1. That `vcvarsall` error is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat), you'll have to set variables.
2. Then you are missing `nvcc` as stated by `WARNING: nvcc not in path.` and similar messages.
3. `numpy` has missing dependent libraries which you should install first.
4. For `boost` you should follow the suggestion and use a prebuilt binary.

All in all I'd say it's all about reading and understanding error messages. As a suggestion: follow the installation guides on the library websites, which will show you dependencies as well.

Comment: can you please help more for nvcc ?

Comment: You have to install [CUDA for Windows](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).

Comment: i install this before

Comment: also reinstall and it's result : Installed:
     - Nsight Monitor and HUD Launcher
     - Nsight C++ AMP Target Support for MSVSMON
Not Installed:
     - Nsight for Visual Studio 2012
       Reason: VS2012 was not found
     - Nsight for Visual Studio 2010
       Reason: VS2010 was not found
     - Nsight for Visual Studio 2008
       Reason: VS2008 SP1 was not found
     - Nsight C++ AMP Debugger for Visual Studio 2012
       Reason: VS2012 was not found

Comment: Seems like it wants to install for VS2012 and you have VS2010.

Comment: i install VS2012 and cuda , numpy , boost and now have some new problem with pycuda

Comment: C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\pycuda-2013.1.1>python setup.py build
 running build
 running build_py
 running build_ext
 building '_driver' extension
 error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

 C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\pygpu\pycuda-2013.1.1>

Comment: There we are again at point #1. Did you read the link I provided?

Comment: i also check configure.py and siteconf.py , in siteconf.py i just dont know what is CXXFLAGS = [] LDFLAGS = []  [last 2 line] and what should i put inside them ? thanks

Comment: There are pre-build binaries [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycuda). No compilation needed...

Comment: hey tnx installed :D , if any question i will ask you , very helpful <3

Comment: You're welcome. But please try Google first and try to read/understand the error message, there is (mostly) no magic behind. Don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: hey friend , i get this error much , nvcc : fatal error : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH , i know must add path of cl.exe in tools , but tell me how to add it , i find something , computer > properties > advance system setting > advance [tab] > environment variables > click new , i think there but what is name of variable ? i know value is the path but what is name ? tnx :D or if have other way tell me

Comment: Why you don't use Google? I instantly found a related SO question: [Compile CUDA without Visual Studio - “Cannot find compiler cl.exe in path”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985860/compile-cuda-without-visual-studio-cannot-find-compiler-cl-exe-in-path).

Comment: i do same , also saw that in google, i add NVCC Variable  with value : C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\bin     and also add Path  D:\Software\VS2012\VC\bin\amd64   but still that error not find cl.exe

Comment: Did you install the Windows SDK as suggested in the post?

Comment: i was install but some problem with x86 and x64 it fixed by reinstall , i ask much :D have question again , you have something more easy to gpu programming with python on windows ? pycuda most use C  .... have something better ?

Comment: I'd suggest to stick to Visual Studio and CUDA.

Comment: tnx dude, i have got other question :D , can we use system() in C and run a python script same system('python sebastian.py') as gpu ? is this possible then i can programming python and finish my work

Comment: There is a Python/C interface. Use the python documentation. You should otherwise ask a new question.

Comment: Okay :D i make new question tapic in few second tnQ

Comment: please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908882/can-we-run-a-class-as-gpu-using-pycuda  thanks