# CUDAfy with Visual C# Express 2010 and Windows 8

Tags: c#, cuda, nvcc

Has anyone succeeded in getting the sample CUDAfy C# projects to run?

I am getting this error when CudafyTranslator.Cudafy() is executed:

```
{Cudafy.CudafyCompileException: Compilation error: nvcc : fatal error : Visual Studio configuration file '(null)' could not be found for installation at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin/../..'

   at Cudafy.CudafyModule.Compile(eGPUCompiler mode, Boolean deleteGeneratedCode)
   at Cudafy.Translator.CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(ePlatform platform, eArchitecture arch, Version cudaVersion, Boolean compile, Type[] types)
   at Cudafy.Translator.CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(ePlatform platform, eArchitecture arch, Type[] types)
   at Cudafy.Translator.CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(ePlatform platform)
   at CudafyExamples.Arrays.ArrayBasicIndexing.Execute() in C:\Users\Michael Routitski\Downloads\CudafyV1.12\CudafyV1.12\CudafyExamples\Arrays\ArrayBasicIndexing.cs:line 40}
```

I tried looking for solutions and tried the solutions suggested in

[CUDA linking error - Visual Express 2008 - nvcc fatal due to (null) configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970493/cuda-linking-error-visual-express-2008-nvcc-fatal-due-to-null-configuratio)

I also installed the Windows Development SDK 8 and it did not help . I could not find the file that launches the WD SDK configuration tool... (Problem with Windows 8?)

This seems to be common problem with integrating CUDA compiler with Visual C#/C++ Express...

Comment: I had no problems getting the example to compile once I installed the proper SDK.

Comment: try setting CompileProperties.WorkingDirectory amd Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() to the same value