# Cudafy - how to pass machine32 to nvcc

Tags: cuda

Am trying to get the [cudafy.net](http://cudafy.codeplex.com/) examples to compile on my 64bit machine.  Am stuck on the error:

fatal error... '(null)' could not be found

which seems to be fixed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970493/cuda-linking-error-visual-express-2008-nvcc-fatal-due-to-null-configuratio):

by passing  `--machine 32` argument to `nvcc` call

Question:  How do I do that in the VS2010 solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CudafyTranslator.Cudafy() method has several overloads.
For example [this](http://www.hybriddsp.com/Portals/0/cudafy/html/bf773c5e-fbe2-f1e6-f0b1-e8f7fc0079f6.htm) overload takes an ePlatform Enum value that defines for what platform (Auto, x86, x64 or both) you want your kernels to be compiled.